# How can I "undelete" a set of documents in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

I have a large set of documents in a CouchDB database that were just accidentally bulk deleted using `_deleted:true`.  I also have a backup for this set of data that includes their last known good revision and metadata.  I need to maintain the same `_id`, so simple restore with a new `_id` is not an option.

Compaction has not been run and I can access any of these documents via the `&rev=` url parameter as well as their attachments (which are needed).

What I need to do is "restore" these documents to the revision I have on file.  Surprisingly, I have come up empty with any queries on how to achieve this.  Tips or hacks appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just `PUT` the whole document, including the attachment stub, back into the DB, with the deleted rev, but less the `_deleted:true` parameter, then all will be well.

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it is correct, but with one important caveat-- which is that the `_attachments` property must exist still in the `_deleted` document.  If you've nixed out this property, you can attempt a metadata restore, but will be met with this error message instead: `{"error":"missing_stub","reason":"id:777a5466a2ecd90a288ce38f4422a82bf, name:myattachment"}`.  The solution in this case (as was mine, actually) is to run a batch job to retrieve the attachments from the old revisions, restore the document properties from your backup, then re-attach the files you just batched down

Comment: I assumed that when you said that you'd deleted the documents by using `_deleted:true` that you hadn't removed the `_attachments` stubs.  If you removed them then yeah, you'll need to restore them from elsewhere.